# Can we update user in Keycloak based on any other unique fields other than id?

Tags: java, .net, single-sign-on, keycloak

I am trying to update users info in Keycloak, I was able to update the user using id provided  in the keycloak.

I tried  with this endpoint and i was able to update using id

```
 PUT /admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}
```

Is there any way by which i can update the same user using the email-id as this is also a unique field? i tried replacing {id} with email-id of user but that gave me a error.
Is there any way by which i can update the user using email-id or any other unique field of user

Answer (score 1):

This is not an available feature on Keycloak actually. You can check the documentation of the REST API [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/3.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource).
You can always do the workaround getting all the users, parse it looking for the email you want, extract the ID and finally use it for updating its data.

1. `GET /admin/realms/{realm}/users/`
2. You will receive a JSON object containing all the users, parse it with [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson#gson) or other JSON parsing library. Then if you parsed it in an class called `User`, use its `#getId()` method.
3. `PUT /admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}`

You can have a look at Keycloak's [UserRepresentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/3.0/rest-api/index.html#_userrepresentation) to know what attributes your User object will need.

If you don't know how to use Gson read their documentation or perform a fast google search.

**P.S.**: Gson is case sensitive so your attributes should have the same names than the one provided in the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

You can not update User with email-id, Option is to set email-id for username and search with following API. Once found the user then update the user.

```
GET /admin/realms/{realm}/users
```

Also note Search operation is not exact match search, searching on `chris@example.com` will return both `amy.chris@example.com`, `chris@example.com`.